# Does javascript on iOS have to be downloaded *by* the WebKit framework in addition to executing within its framework?

Tags: ios, app-store

The agreement says this:

3.3.2 An Internal Use Application may not download or install executable code. Interpreted code may only be used in an Application if all scripts, code and interpreters are packaged in the Application and not downloaded. The only exception to the foregoing is scripts and code downloaded and run by Apple's built-in WebKit framework.

It particular it says ".. code downloaded .. by Webkit framework".

Does anybody know if for a native app using UIWebView this means Javascript has to be downloaded automatically by Webkit i.e. as a consequence of the user clicking on an external url link. Or if it would be acceptable for the scripts to be downloaded by creating my own HTTP connection to a server and downloading them myself - but they would be executed within Webkit (via UIWebView) ?

I presume this restriction is for security purposes, so does the security come from limiting the execution to within WebKit, as opposed to where the scripts are downloaded from?

I realize its unlikely anybody can definitively answer this except Apple, but speculate answers are very welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Web apps are a different category from Applications.

Comment: If you'll notice you'll see I mentioned UIWebView - hence I'm asking regarding a native app using javascript. Though I've edited the original text to now explicitly mention native app.

Comment: Not an authoritative answer, of course, but there are several document viewers, editors and web browsers approved by Apple and in the App store that start HTML5 page downloads from bookmarks, etc. outside of web view clicks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception that Apple is making is based upon the sandboxed nature of Webkit/UIWebView - in effect, it provides an "allowed" scriptable environment precisely because it is so well sandboxed. If you provide a UIWebView, it doesn't make any real difference if the user navigates to a site that then executes some Javascript in the browser, versus you programmatically getting some Javascript via NSURLConnection or other way, and then loading that into the UIWebView be reloading an HTML file or using "stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString".

Comment: I notice that it says "... scripts and code ...". So I hope/assume that Objective-C can be downloaded and executed in addition to Javascript. If its done within Webkit I don't see any reason why not. Anybody know any different?

Comment: Webkit has no capability to execute Objective-C.  I don't even think the Objective-C run-time can do that - that is, Objective-C does not have the equivalent of Perl's "eval" which enables you to execute arbitrary code at run-time.  If you think about it, if you could pass Objective C to your app at run-time, this would completely circumvent the app store approval process.  Again, this is allowed in the case of HTML and JavaScript because those are sandboxed in a very proven way within WebKit.